# TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I start a root screen with a "file select" and a "go" button. The go button is disabled and I want to make it active after the file has been selected.  When I select the file go should become active but instead this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment" Here is some sample code

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog

def chooseDir():
    dir1=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='choose file path')
    go['state']=Tkinter.ACTIVE
root=Tkinter.Tk()
global go
go=Tkinter.Button(text='file location',command=chooseDir,state=Tkinter.DISABLED).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line:

```
go=Tkinter.Button(text='file location',command=chooseDir,state=Tkinter.DISABLED).pack()
```

is creating a temporary object, then calling pack() on it. The pack method returns None, so `go` is assigned None.

Remove the .pack() then `go` will be the Button object. Then call `go.pack()`.

Answer (score 1):

(update for new error)
`go` doesn't exist in that scope, you'll need to get access to it somehow, or by using the one in the global scope using `global go` inside the `chooseDir` method perhaps

`Tkinter.Button`s don't behave like dictionaries, you can change their status via the [`config()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) method.

Try:

```
go.config(state=Tkinter.ACTIVE)
```

Comment: Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: You need to put `global go` inside the `chooseDir` method if you want to bring in the `go` from the global scope.