# How do i disable a button in tkinter and change text in it python

Tags: python, tkinter

im making a restaurant management system and i want to disable a button and change its text to "Booked!" this is for the table booking system

```
Table1 = Button(f1ab, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black",font=("Clarity Gothic SF", 16, "bold"), width=5,
                text="Table 1", command=button_click).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I dont know what function to use. ive already got a name for it but idk what to put in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Tkinter Button state from disabled to normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046743/how-to-change-tkinter-button-state-from-disabled-to-normal)

Comment: i have tried the suggestion and it seems to not work for me 
it says "nonetype object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Then you didn't do it correctly. Or are you suggesting that the accepted answer with 77 upvotes is incorrect? Anyway, without a [mre] and full stacktrace we can't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution to change text and state:

You can change the button by using `state`.

`Table1['state'] = DISABLED` or `Table1.config(state=DISABLE)`

*Note: To disable a button, use `DISABLE`, to enable it again, use `NORMAL`.*

---

Use the same method to change the text.

`Table1['text'] = 'something'` or `Table1.config(text='something')`

#### Solution for the TypeError:

The reason why the error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment` is raised is because you used `.grid()` when declaring `Table1`:

```
Table1 = Button(f1ab, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black",font=("Clarity Gothic SF", 16, "bold"), width=5,
                text="Table 1", command=button_click).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

You can just fix it by separating that line into 2:

```
Table1 = Button(f1ab, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black",font=("Clarity Gothic SF", 16, "bold"), width=5,
                text="Table 1", command=button_click)
Table1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

---

#### The code should be:

**The function**:

```
def button_click():
    Table1['state'] = DISABLED
    Table1['text'] = 'Booked!'
```

---

**Full code**:

```
from tkinter import *

f1ab = Tk()


def button_click():
    Table1['state'] = DISABLED
    Table1['text'] = 'Booked!'


Table1 = Button(f1ab, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg="black", font=("Clarity Gothic SF", 16, "bold"), width=5,
                text="Table 1", command=button_click)
Table1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

---

For more detail, visit:

1. [Change Button State](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/change-button-state)
2. [TypeError Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975250/17990633)